# Question about merge two sorted list(leetcode question 21)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

```
public ListNode mergeTwoLists(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
    ListNode head = new ListNode(0);
    ListNode handler = head;
    while(l1 != null && l2 != null) {
        if (l1.val <= l2.val) {
            handler.next = l1;
            l1 = l1.next;
        } else {
            handler.next = l2;
            l2 = l2.next;
        }
        handler = handler.next;
    }
    
    if (l1 != null) {
        handler.next = l1;
    } else if (l2 != null) {
        handler.next = l2;
    }
    //I think the answer should be added one more sentence below

    //head.next = handler;

    return head.next;
}
```

Hello, I am stuck at understanding why the answer return "head.next"?

I think there should be one more sentence as I made comments.

It is not clear for me to understand how head and handler are connected

for example, for sudo code

int a = 3;
int b = a;

b = 5;

then "a" is still "3" not "5"

anyone can explain this conceptually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess if you'd read [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_node), would clear that up. Technically, in your code, `head.next` would be similar to the *header node* in the following picture:

> a sentinel node is a specifically designated node used with linked
> lists and trees as a traversal path terminator. This type of node does
> not hold or reference any data managed by the data structure.

Adding a sentinel node to a Linked List would make that Linked List similar to a [Header Linked List](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/header-linked-list-in-c/). Header Linked List is simply a Linked List with just one additional Node right in the beginning.

[image]

#### Steps:

- We'd create a (sentinel) node.
- We'd connect it to the head or start of the linked list
- We'd ignore that (sentinel) node, and we'd do whatever else is necessary to do, here we'd focus on merging two lists.
- Finally, in the `return` statement, we'd return `sentinel.next`, which is the head or start node.

```
public ListNode mergeTwoLists(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
    ListNode sentinel = new ListNode(0);
    ListNode head = sentinel;

    while (l1 != null && l2 != null) {
        if (l1.val <= l2.val) {
            head.next = l1;
            l1 = l1.next;

        } else {
            head.next = l2;
            l2 = l2.next;
        }

        head = head.next;
    }

    if (l1 != null) {
        head.next = l1;

    } else if (l2 != null) {
        head.next = l2;
    }

    return sentinel.next;
}
```

You can solve the problem without that though, recursively:

```
public class Solution {
    public static final ListNode mergeTwoLists(final ListNode l1, final ListNode l2) {
        if (l1 == null) {
            return l2;
        }

        if (l2 == null) {
            return l1;
        }

        final ListNode merged;

        if (l1.val < l2.val) {
            merged = l1;
            merged.next = mergeTwoLists(l1.next, l2);

        } else {
            merged = l2;
            merged.next = mergeTwoLists(l1, l2.next);
        }

        return merged;
    }
}
```

Here is a more readable Python version, iteratively:

```
class Solution:
    def mergeTwoLists(self, l1, l2):
        sentinel = ptr = ListNode(-1)
        while l1 and l2:
            if l1.val < l2.val:
                ptr.next = l1
                l1 = l1.next
            else:
                ptr.next = l2
                l2 = l2.next
            ptr = ptr.next
        ptr.next = l1 or l2
        return sentinel.next
```

Similarly in C++,

```
static const struct Solution {
    ListNode* mergeTwoLists(
        ListNode* l1,
        ListNode* l2
    ) {
        ListNode sentinel(0);
        ListNode* head = &sentinel;

        while (l1 && l2) {
            if (l1->val < l2->val) {
                head->next = l1;
                l1 = l1->next;

            } else {
                head->next = l2;
                l2 = l2->next;
            }

            head = head->next;
        }

        head->next = l1 ? l1 : l2;
        return sentinel.next;
    }
};
```

---

### References

- For additional details, please see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-two-sorted-lists/discuss/) where you can find plenty of well-explained accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) including low-complexity algorithms and asymptotic [runtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup>.
- [LinkedList](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Sentinel_nodes)
- [Circular Linked List](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/header-linked-list-in-c/)

Answer (score 0):

ListNode head = new ListNode(0);
This line creates a dummy node making it easier to attach future nodes to this list. Once the processing is done it does head.next to return and from next node and not return the dummy node.
Eg.

l1->1->.2->3

l2->4->5

head->0

After merging

head->0-> 1-> 2-> 3-> 4-> 5

if you do return head; then output will be  0-> 1-> 2-> 3-> 4-> 5
where 0 is extra. Hence return **head.next** which returns 1-> 2-> 3-> 4-> 5
is correct.

Also int a = 3; int b = a;
b = 5;
then "a" is still "3" not "5"
This is true for a primitive data typed which does copy by value and not by reference
Read this for clarity
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Call-by-value-and-Call-by-reference-in-Java

Answer (score 0):

A dummy node is used in languages that don't support pointers. In C or C++, using a pointer to pointer to node can be used to merge two linked lists:

```
NODE * Merge(NODE *pNode0, NODE *pNode1)
{
NODE *pMrg;                             /* ptr to node, will be merged list */
NODE **ppMrg = &pMrg;                   /* ptr to ptr to node */
    if(pNode0 == NULL)                  /* if either list empty, */
        return pNode1;                  /*  return the other */
    if(pNode1 == NULL)
        return pNode0;
    while(1){                           /* merge the lists */
        if(pNode0->data <= pNode1->data){
            *ppMrg = pNode0;
            ppMrg = &(pNode0->next);
            pNode0 = *ppMrg;
            if(pNode0 == NULL){
                *ppMrg = pNode1;
                break;}}
        else{
            *ppMrg = pNode1;
            ppMrg = &(pNode1->next);
            pNode1 = *ppMrg;
            if(pNode1 == NULL){
                *ppMrg = pNode0;
                break;}}}
    return pMrg;
}
```